# How Ktor server can serve ressource files on local and hosted environment?

Tags: kotlin, server, resources, freemarker, ktor

I built a Ktor server and I'm trying to display datas on webpages with FreeMarker engine. On my local host I store files inside the resources directory of my intelliJ IDE like this:

```
myProject
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── kotlin
│   │   │   └── com.example.mypackage
│   │   │       ├── Main.kt
│   │   │       ├── utils
│   │   │       │   └── MyResourceReader.kt
│   │   │       └── ...
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── database
│   │       │   ├── data1.json
│   │       │   ├── data2.json
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       ├── static
│   │       │   ├── css
│   │       │   │   ├── style.css
│   │       │   │   └── ...
│   │       │   ├── js
│   │       │   │   ├── function.js
│   │       │   │   └── ...
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       ├── templates
│   │       │   ├── index.ftl
│   │       │   └── ...
│   │       └── ...
│   └── test
│       └── ...
└── build.gradle.kts
```

From the MyResourceReader.kt file, I can acces all my resources directory and files and serve them in get request like this:

```
val resourcesCss ={}.javaClass.getResource("/static/css/style.css").path
val resourcesJs ={}.javaClass.getResource("/static/js/function.js").path
val resourcesJson ={}.javaClass.getResource("/databse/data1.json").path

get("/static/css/style.css") {
        call.respondFile(File(resourcesCss ))     
}
```

But it's different from the server:

```
myProject/
├── database
│   ├── data1.json
│   ├── data2.json
│   └── ...
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── function.js
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── templates
│   ├── index.ftl
│   └── ...
└── myProject.jar
```

The server host does not load these files and cannot display them. That is certainly a problem of path but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I still haven't solved my problem. Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried the methods described in the documentation for serving static content? https://ktor.io/docs/serving-static-content.html

Comment: Thanks. These methods can suit me for my .js or .css files but I also have .json files inside my database folder that I read and write. Are those json also considered as static content ?

Comment: Are those JSON files packed inside a JAR or stored in a local filesystem?